# How to reset the Modal input states after clicking the modal close button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-modal, react-props

After giving the input of mobile number when i close the modal, then again after clicking the `Form Submit` button, input box shows the previously entered number. I believe model captures the previous state by itself and i want to clear it whenever we open the modal.

After entering the OTP input in Modal, if we click on the `Edit mobile number` and when we again enter the input in mobile number, then previously entered OTP also shows up. I want to clear it after entering the new mobile number.

I have already tried setting the state to ("") on the onclick events but it doesn't help.

I could really use some help.

**Code:**

```
export default function Form() {
  // form default hooks
  const {register,handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isValid },} = useForm({mode: "onChange",criteriaMode: "all",});
  const {register: register2,handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,formState: { errors: errors2 },} = useForm({mode: "onChange",});
  const [verifyOTPFlag, setVerifyOTPFlag] = useState(true);
  //modal hooks
  const [mobileNumberInput, setMobileNumberInput] = useState(true);
  const [postVerificationMessage, setPostVerificationMessage] = useState();
  const [otpVerificationResult, setOtpVerificationResult] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [otpInput, setShowOtpInput] = useState(false);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [OTP, setOTP] = useState("");
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(59);
  // post office and aadhar hooks
  const [districtName, setDistrictName] = React.useState("");
  const [stateName, setStateName] = React.useState("");
  //-------------------------modal functionalities start-------------------------
  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setShowOtpInput(false);};

  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow(true);};

  const showOtpInput = () => {
    getOTP(number);
    setOTP("");
    setShowOtpInput(true);
    setMobileNumberInput(false);
    setOtpVerificationResult(false);
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    data["district"] = districtName;
    data["state"] = stateName;
    setMobileNumberInput(true);
    setPostVerificationMessage("");
    setNumber("");

    if (verifyOTPFlag) {
      if (isValid) {
        setShow(true);
      } else {}
    } 
  };

  const onSubmit2 = () => {
    verifyOTP(OTP)
      .then((resp) => {
        alert("OTP verification Successful");
        setPostVerificationMessage(<p className="text-danger">OTP verification Successful</p>);
        setVerifyOTPFlag(false);
        setOtpVerificationResult(true);
        setShowOtpInput(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setPostVerificationMessage(<p className="text-danger"> OTP verification Failed. Kindly enter the correct OTP</p> )      
        setOtpVerificationResult(true);
      });};

  const onClickEditMobileNo = () => {
    setShowOtpInput(!otpInput);
    setOtpVerificationResult("");
    setOTP("");
    setMobileNumberInput(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="container mt-2">
            <label className="control-label">Full Name : </label>
            <input
              className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              {...register("username", {
                required: "Username is Required",
                pattern: {
                  value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,\'-\/:&]*$/,
                  message: "Entered value does not match valid name format",
                },
              })}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{errors.username?.message}</p>

            <label className="control-label">C/o : </label>
            <input
              className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
              type="text"
              name="careof"
              {...register("careof", {
                required: "Name of c/o is Required",
                pattern: {
                  value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,\'-\/:&]*$/,
                  message: "Entered value does not match valid name format",
                },
              })}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{errors.careof?.message}</p>

            <label className="control-label">House No./Bldg./Apt : </label>
            <input
              className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
              type="text"
              name="houseno"
              {...register("houseno", {
                required: "House number is Required",
              })}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{errors.houseno?.message}</p>

            <div className="text-center">
              <button
                className="button btn-primary btn px-3 mr-1"
                onClick={onSubmit}
              >
                Form Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit2(onSubmit2)}>
          {/* modal starts */}
          <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} backdrop="static">
            <Modal.Header
              style={{
                backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(180deg , #3f55c4 , #95a4f0",
              }}
              closeButton></Modal.Header>

            <Collapse in={mobileNumberInput}>
              <div
                className="input-field-sb mt-4 ml-5"
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              >
                <input className="input-sb" maxLength="10" type="text" id="mobile"
                  // onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
                  {...register2("mobile", {
                    required: "Mobile number is Required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^[5-9]\d{9}$/,
                      message: "Entered value does not match valid name format",
                    },
                    onChange: (e) => setNumber(e.target.value),})}/>
                <p className="errorMsg">{errors2.mobile?.message}</p>
                <label className="label-sb" htmlFor="mobile">Enter Mobile Number: </label>
              </div>
            </Collapse>

            <Modal.Body>
              <Collapse in={otpInput}>
                <div>
                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <p className="text-center"><strong>{" "} We sent you a code to verify your mobile number{" "}</strong>{" "}
                      <b className="text-danger">{number}</b>
                      <span className="mobile-text"> Enter your OTP code here</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <input className="input-sbj" maxLength="6" onChange={(e) => setOTP(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
              </Collapse>

              <Collapse in={otpVerificationResult}>
                <div className="text-center">{postVerificationMessage}</div>
              </Collapse>

              <div className="d-flex justify-content-center col-md-12">
                {otpInput ? (
                  <Button className="px-5 align-middle mt-4" variant="secondary" onClick={onSubmit2}>{" "} Verify</Button>) : (
                  <Button className="px-5 align-middle mt-4" variant="secondary"
                    onClick={errors2.mobile ? null : showOtpInput}>
                    {" "} Send OTP </Button>)}
              </div>

              <div className="row">
                <div className={otpInput ? "col-sm-6" : "col-sm-6 d-none"}>
                  <a className="btn">Resend OTP in 00:{counter}</a>
                </div>
                <div
                  className={otpInput? "text-right col-sm-6": "text-right col-sm-6 d-none"}>
                  <a className="btn" onClick={onClickEditMobileNo}> Edit Mobile number </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </form>
        {/* modal ends */}
      </div></div>);}
```

Comment: Is your page refreshing after submitting?

Comment: no sir, because i want to keep my form data. i just want my modal data to be cleared.

Comment: If you have any other solution which can work over here then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be just adding `e.target.reset()` in your onSubmit function.

```
const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
data["district"] = districtName;
data["state"] = stateName;
setMobileNumberInput(true);
setPostVerificationMessage("");
setNumber("");
e.target.reset();

if (verifyOTPFlag) {
  if (isValid) {
    setShow(true);
  } else {}
}
};
```

also keep the `setNumber("")` like this. I think this will solve the problem.

Comment: Sir, this has only reset the data in my normal form fields. Modal, still has previous values in it. Also,i do not want my normal form input boxes to be cleared. I just want my modal states to be cleared which is not happening.

Comment: can you put the code in sandbox and share the link here...?

Comment: Shared the codesandbox link in the question. Also, sharing it here for your reference. 
  https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-issue-2sutln