# How to clear the Modal states after closing it or before opening it again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, bootstrap-modal

After giving the input of mobile number when i close the modal, then again after clicking the `Form Submit` button, input box shows the previously entered number. I believe model captures the previous state by itself and i want to clear it whenever we open the modal.

After entering the OTP input in Modal, if we click on the `Edit mobile number` and when we again enter the input in mobile number, then previously entered OTP also shows up. I want to clear it after entering the new mobile number.

I have already tried setting the state to ("") on the onclick events but it doesn't help.

I could really use some help.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-issue-2sutln)

**Code:**

```
export default function Form() {

  const {register,handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isValid },} = useForm({mode: "onChange",criteriaMode: "all",});
  const {register: register2,handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,formState: { errors: errors2 },} = useForm({mode: "onChange",});
  const [verifyOTPFlag, setVerifyOTPFlag] = useState(true);
  //modal hooks
  const [mobileNumberInput, setMobileNumberInput] = useState(true);
  const [postVerificationMessage, setPostVerificationMessage] = useState();
  const [otpVerificationResult, setOtpVerificationResult] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [otpInput, setShowOtpInput] = useState(false);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [OTP, setOTP] = useState("");
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(59);
  // post office and aadhar hooks
  const [districtName, setDistrictName] = React.useState("");
  const [stateName, setStateName] = React.useState("");
  //-------------------------modal functionalities start-------------------------
  const handleClose = () => {
    setShow(false);
    setShowOtpInput(false);};

  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow(true);};

  const showOtpInput = () => {
    getOTP(number);
    setOTP("");
    setShowOtpInput(true);
    setMobileNumberInput(false);
    setOtpVerificationResult(false);
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    data["district"] = districtName;
    data["state"] = stateName;
    setMobileNumberInput(true);
    setPostVerificationMessage("");
    setNumber("");

    if (verifyOTPFlag) {
      if (isValid) {
        setShow(true);
      } else {}
    } 
  };

  const onSubmit2 = () => {
    verifyOTP(OTP)
      .then((resp) => {
        alert("OTP verification Successful");
        setPostVerificationMessage(<p className="text-danger">OTP verification Successful</p>);
        setVerifyOTPFlag(false);
        setOtpVerificationResult(true);
        setShowOtpInput(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setPostVerificationMessage(<p className="text-danger"> OTP verification Failed. Kindly enter the correct OTP</p> )      
        setOtpVerificationResult(true);
      });};

  const onClickEditMobileNo = () => {
    setShowOtpInput(!otpInput);
    setOtpVerificationResult("");
    setOTP("");
    setMobileNumberInput(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="container mt-2">
            <label className="control-label">Full Name : </label>
            <input
              className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              {...register("username", {
                required: "Username is Required",
                pattern: {
                  value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,\'-\/:&]*$/,
                  message: "Entered value does not match valid name format",
                },
              })}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{errors.username?.message}</p>

            <label className="control-label">C/o : </label>
            <input
              className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
              type="text"
              name="careof"
              {...register("careof", {
                required: "Name of c/o is Required",
                pattern: {
                  value: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\s,\'-\/:&]*$/,
                  message: "Entered value does not match valid name format",
                },
              })}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{errors.careof?.message}</p>

            <label className="control-label">House No./Bldg./Apt : </label>
            <input
              className="text-uppercase input-group input-group-lg form-control"
              type="text"
              name="houseno"
              {...register("houseno", {
                required: "House number is Required",
              })}
            />
            <p className="errorMsg">{errors.houseno?.message}</p>

            <div className="text-center">
              <button
                className="button btn-primary btn px-3 mr-1"
                onClick={onSubmit}
              >
                Form Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit2(onSubmit2)}>
          {/* modal starts */}
          <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} backdrop="static">
            <Modal.Header
              style={{
                backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(180deg , #3f55c4 , #95a4f0",
              }}
              closeButton></Modal.Header>

            <Collapse in={mobileNumberInput}>
              <div
                className="input-field-sb mt-4 ml-5"
                style={{ width: "80%" }}
              >
                <input className="input-sb" maxLength="10" type="text" id="mobile"
                  // onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
                  {...register2("mobile", {
                    required: "Mobile number is Required",
                    pattern: {
                      value: /^[5-9]\d{9}$/,
                      message: "Entered value does not match valid name format",
                    },
                    onChange: (e) => setNumber(e.target.value),})}/>
                <p className="errorMsg">{errors2.mobile?.message}</p>
                <label className="label-sb" htmlFor="mobile">Enter Mobile Number: </label>
              </div>
            </Collapse>

            <Modal.Body>
              <Collapse in={otpInput}>
                <div>
                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <p className="text-center"><strong>{" "} We sent you a code to verify your mobile number{" "}</strong>{" "}
                      <b className="text-danger">{number}</b>
                      <span className="mobile-text"> Enter your OTP code here</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <input className="input-sbj" maxLength="6" onChange={(e) => setOTP(e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
              </Collapse>

              <Collapse in={otpVerificationResult}>
                <div className="text-center">{postVerificationMessage}</div>
              </Collapse>

              <div className="d-flex justify-content-center col-md-12">
                {otpInput ? (
                  <Button className="px-5 align-middle mt-4" variant="secondary" onClick={onSubmit2}>{" "} Verify</Button>) : (
                  <Button className="px-5 align-middle mt-4" variant="secondary"
                    onClick={errors2.mobile ? null : showOtpInput}>
                    {" "} Send OTP </Button>)}
              </div>

              <div className="row">
                <div className={otpInput ? "col-sm-6" : "col-sm-6 d-none"}>
                  <a className="btn">Resend OTP in 00:{counter}</a>
                </div>
                <div
                  className={otpInput? "text-right col-sm-6": "text-right col-sm-6 d-none"}>
                  <a className="btn" onClick={onClickEditMobileNo}> Edit Mobile number </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </form>
        {/* modal ends */}
      </div></div>)
;}
```

Comment: This is a wall of code. You need to remove all irrelevant code from this or people won't even bother looking at it.

Comment: codesandbox link ?

Comment: Shared the codesandbox link. Please guide me.  https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-issue-2sutln

Comment: Why did you ask the exact same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487296/how-to-reset-the-modal-input-states-after-clicking-the-modal-close-button-in-rea Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

when applying modal, generally you can use this approach.
when you submit, clear your modal fields states so it will be like it opened for the first time when you open it again.
you can do this for when you toggle or close.

this will mean that whenever you open the modal next time it will open with clean (empty or default) data.

Comment: I have tried that Sir but got no help with it. I have cleared the states of Modal on submit button function but even after that somehow, modal has captured the previous data.

Comment: you are using the input in the modal as a uncontrolled input. because the modal are usually rendered when the parent in mounted, your input  is uncontrolled it keeps the value added to it. you can give it the value "number" and then on handleClose() method set the number to "" and this will clear the number added previously, please also take care/clear any error messages that are set

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-issue-forked-bjw6fv?file=/src/Form.js
please check i have made it controlled and handled the input value to clear,

Comment: Thank you sir for your solution, it worked for phone number. Sir, do i have to follow the same approach for OTP issue as well(problem statement 2)?

Comment: i think since you are using react-hook-form for your validation, please check its methods,for the proper approach you have to unregister when you are closing the modal and then register when you are showing the modal for validation to work properly.

Comment: Okay sir, i will look into the same. However, if you can please guide me, how can i set otp state to ("") on edit number button click event. Because general approach is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245294/discussion-between-imran-qureshi-and-anshul).